# Stripe - Error : This product cannot be deleted because it has one or more user-created prices

Tags: stripe-payments

I tried calling Stripe Api to create a product with a default price .

```json
stripe.products.create({
    name : name,
    description : description,
    metadata : {
        userID : profileId
    },
    default_price_data : {
        currency : "eur",
        unit_amount_decimal : price,
    },
    expand: ['default_price'],

},{
    stripeAccount : accountId
})
```

But when I tried to delete the created product it gave me an error which says:

> This product cannot be deleted because it has one or more user-created prices.

Then , I tried to delete the Associated Price to the product.

Surprisingly, **There isn't a stripe call to delete a price** ! so I just tried to make
**active=false** by calling update price call :

```json
stripe.prices.update(stripePriceId , { active : false} ,{
    stripeAccount : stripeAccountId
} )
```

Unfortunately , I still got the same error. How can I delete this product?

> For technical reasons : I must delete the product **using Stripe API and** **not Stripe Dashboard**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is just impossible. Once a Product has associated Prices, it can not be deleted via the API. This is a limitation of Stripe's API as they discourage data deletion in general. Instead they recommend setting `active: false` on the `Product` and/or the `Price`s directly.

This ensures that you have complete data in your system when you do data analysis or reconciliation later and avoids developers deleting data now they will likely need in months or years down the road and regret deleting.

The Dashboard option is here more as an escape hatch that you wouldn't use at scale.

Comment: Thank you for you answer , Yeah it seems that the only way to simulate the product deletion in STRIPE Api .... Hopefully , they will add it in their next releases

Comment: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/issues/658
Follow this issue and raise your voice so Stripe give support to delete prices and products through API.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an automation script that simplifies the process of deleting archived products on the Stripe dashboard. This script uses Selenium in the background to perform the task seamlessly, saving valuable time during development and testing.

To use this solution, follow these steps:

1. Clone the repository: [Stripe Product Deletion Automation](https://github.com/MilovanTomasevic/stripe-product-deletion)
2. Install Selenium: `pip install selenium`
3. Open the `main.py` file and provide your Stripe login credentials:

   ```py
   USER_EMAIL = "ENTER_EMAIL"
   USER_PASSWORD = "ENTER_PASSWORD"
   ```
4. Run the script: `python main.py`

The script will log in to your Stripe account and take care of deleting archived products. Enjoy the time saved!